# Can I use GNU make's SHELL variable to connect to a remote shell?

Tags: testing, gnu-make

One of the projects I'm working on uses gnu make for testing. I would like to test on a platform that doesn't have a make implementation, but does have a POSIX shell.

Is it possible to create a script (preferably in python) that can "stitch" a remote shell to make, and put it in make's SHELL environment variable?

If not, is there another way anyone can think of to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

Create a script that forwards commands to a remote host. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
shift # remove -c argument
exec ssh remote_host "$@"
```

And make it executable (`chmod +x`).

And then in Makefile:

```
SHELL := './my_shell.sh'
all :
    @echo `hostname` is making $@
```

Outputs:

```
$ make
remote_host.peer1.net is making all
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have potential. What about the environment variables, though? IIRC, make transfers some to the shell (such as current working directory, for example). Is there a good way to know what environment variables make passes on?

Comment: All environment variables become make variables. ssh though doesn't transfer environment variables to the remote host. Use command line arguments instead.

Comment: So these variables aren't passed to the shell? not even stuff like PWD?

Comment: Processes spawned by `make` inherit all environment variables. `ssh` doesn't pass environment variables to the remote host _by default_. `ssh` client and server must be configured to send and accept environment variables.

Comment: It's good enough for me. I will just extract what I need from the local environment. Thanks again.